# Sending a list to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a page on my little project where I want to list all users in my database to a page.

At the moment I'm at the select statement, but I dont know how to pass it to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  SqlConnection connection = new ...
  connection.Open();

  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM users", connection);

  ???
```

How do I pass it to the view and how do I list all the items? Any suggestions?

Comment: I strongly suggest you take a look at 'Separation of Concerns' - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_Concerns. You should not have database calls directly in your actions and should always endeavour to abstract them into separate layers.

Comment: thanks you for your comment, but this a rather small project so i just want it done :D

Comment: That's a terrible reason IMO. You're only creating technical debt for yourself.

Comment: Agreed. Though I don't think it is necessary to debate that here as his question is about retrieving data in the view. Whatever ideological choices he has made elsewhere are irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is populate ViewData.Model with your list of users. So try this:

```
//Same code as you already have...

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

List<CustomUserObject> userList = new List<CustomUserObject>();

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
     //Create a class to house your user object before this next part will work.
     CustomUserObject cuo = new CustomUserObject { FirstName = dt.Rows[0]["FirstName"].ToString(), LastName = dt.Rows[0]["LastName"].ToString(), etc... };
     userList.Add(cuo);
}

ViewData.Model = userList;

return View();
```

Now, assuming you haven't created the view for your action method yet, right click somewhere inside the action method (in Visual Studio) and create view. Make sure the view has Strongly Typed View selected. Set the view model to `IEnumerable<CustomUserObject>`. Now when you are in the view you would reference your model like this.

```
<% foreach (CustomUserObject cuo in Model)
{ %>
     <%: Html.TextBoxFor(cuo.FirstName) %>
     <!-- More controls for all properties on your user object... -->
<% } %>
```

Comment: Now of course Dan Atkinson, the comment under your post, is correct. I recommend throwing out the SqlConnection stuff and going with LINQ and the Entity Framework for the benefit of strongly-typed queries, but that's another topic altogether since your question was only about how to reference data within the view.

Comment: I can't comment on other answers yet until I have 50 rep, but I just wanted to say something in regards to Dan's comment. He is absolutely correct. If you are going to be using MVC I strongly recommend you adopt an almost religious adherence to separation of concerns. You should have a whole other class that acts as your Data Model and have that make calls to the database. Even if you don't want to go all out with LINQ to Entities I still recommend factoring out all database related code into a data model/layer and making that your domain model.

Comment: Hmm... i was a little quick. In my aspx page its complaining that my object does not contain public def for GetEnumerator, any quickfixes on this?

Comment: Why cant i just loop thru all the rows in my command and add it to a List<T> and set ViewModel.Model to it and then loop thru it on the aspx page? im still getting the silly must have 'GetEnumerator' function error

Comment: You could do the List<T>. I updated my answer. I forgot to mention that you have to loop through your datatable and create an IEnumerable<T> (or List<T> if that's what you want) of user objects and assign that to the model.

Comment: You were correct. I have not used IEnumerable much so I didn't realize it was not a collection that you could modify. I updated my answer to reflect the use of List<T>.